# How to NOT shorten content - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, all-in-one-event-calendar

I am using the all-in-one event calendar plugin and it provides shortcodes for the user to enter into a post and then it will display the event information. The shortcode is [ai1ec events_limit="3"]. My Loop is below.

```
<?php
  $eventArgs = array(
    'category_name' => 'events_home'
  );
  $eventQuery = new WP_Query( $eventArgs );
  if ($eventQuery->have_posts()) : while ($eventQuery->have_posts()) : $eventQuery->the_post();
?>

  <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php
  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The output result only shows one event and then three dots "...", which I am assuming means the content the being shortened. Is there a way to NOT limit the_content(); I have tried:

```
<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
```

But that only prints out the shortcode text.
Summary: Is there a way to NOT limit the_content();

Answer (score 0):

Is your default setting shows content summary?

In this page from [Wordpress Developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) I've found this:

> Overriding Archive/Single Page Behavior
>
> If the_content() isn’t working
> as you desire (displaying the entire story when you only want the
> content above the  Quicktag, for example) you can override
> the behavior with global $more.

```
//If you need to display all of the content:

// Declare global $more (before the loop).
global $more;
// Set (inside the loop) to display all content, including text below more.
$more = 1;
the_content();
```

Comment: Did you look up the link I gave?